# Android HttpURLConnection POST RequestMethod results in 400 error code

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection, openstreetmap, urlconnection

I have to pass long OpenStreetMaps overpass api url request. As it is too long for GET request I decided to use POST request. Unfortunately changing RequestMethod resolves in 400 error code (with GET method same query results in 200 code).

Here is my HttpURLConnection code:

```
public String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        Log.wtf("JSON","connection started...");
        // Connecting to url

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        urlConnection.connect();
        Log.wtf("KOD",Integer.toString(urlConnection.getResponseCode()));
        // Reading data from url
        iStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.wtf("ExceptionWhileUrlDownload", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You should POST in a normal way. Instead you make it application/json. That was wrong. Moreover you are not posting any data. You are not writing data to an output stream.

Comment: `downloadUrl()` I wonder what you try to download.

Comment: I deleted application/json line but it not helped. I'm trying to download Json OSM response. By GET method whole query was in strUrl but my query became to long in few cases. URL query looks like this: http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json]<long OSM query here>

Comment: You are not posting any data! So how could this ever work? You are not posting that long osm query string.

Comment: Whole query is in URL that I'm using in urlConnection. That worked when I was using GET method. I'm assuming its different in POST method but have no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: Remove the query from the url. Then write that query string to the output stream. After that you can read from the input stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the application/json

Remove the query from the url. Then write that query string to the output stream. After that you can read from the input stream

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error 400 is bad request error. It means you are sending wrong request. As you get HTTP 200 with GET and HTTP 400 with POST, the HTTP Method that you are calling is a GET not a POST. So you can not send a POST request to a GET Method.

Comment: Thank You for answer. According to this: http://overpass-api.de/command_line.html OSM overpass api supports both GET and POST method. Nevertheless if my code is ok then it may not be true...

Comment: The bad request is only caused by the json approach. Not because its a POST. POST is possible but should be done in the right way.